# iOS, Pattern for adjusting content properties in custom subviews

Tags: ios, objective-c

What's the established way to handle a situation where you have some sort of model object, and various properties on it get modified by multiple views and (custom) subviews?

Should the subview have a reference to its container (I don't know if iOS keeps such a reference, but I could set one if necessary), which has the content, and modifies it such?

Should as few views as possible have pointers to the content, and subviews can send messagea to  their containers to modify the content?

something else? I know I can hack something together, but I want a proper design pattern for this.

Comment: I'm a bit unsure why this was downvoted....

Answer (score 1):

The usual - MVC way - is to have a controller object to mediate between the views and models.

You would have one viewController to manage each screenful-of-views view hierarchy and a separate model object which each of the various viewControllers updates.

None of the views or subviews have pointers to the model. Common ways to get data out of a view or subview is through delegation or - if your view is a UIControl subclass - target/action. The delegate (or the location of the action method) would be the view controller. The views should not know about the model, and vice-versa.

if you are going to want one persisting model object through the life of the app, being updated from various view controllers, you will most likely want to use a singleton pattern - [apple docs here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaObjects/CocoaObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH4-SW32) - see also numerous Q&A's here on singletons (globally-accessible objects), and [this link](http://lukeredpath.co.uk/blog/a-note-on-objective-c-singletons.html).

Comment: +1 thanx, i ended up going with the delegate pattern for the view question.  Are you saying its not preferred to send a message to the childview to configure itself when something changes?  Instead the view controller for that view should reach in and configure the subviews?

Comment: Yes it's preferable for the view controller to manage this, although the actual answer will depend on design specifics. For example, what kind of changes? Where are those initiated? If a view is to communicate directly with its sub view, where is it's changing data coming from? You are likely to end up tightly coupling your view and its sub views so it only makes sense if you are building a reusable custom widget like a custom control object.

Comment: @hvgotcodes - reading your other questions and solutions it seems you are trying to create a reusable control object complete with its own xib. I am doing something similar,in this case it does seem reasonable for the outer view to take on the role of a controller for its sub views as you need a single point of contact ( public interface) for the custom object.